# Is it possible to transfer files from my Galaxy S3 to my ARM Chromebook?

Tags: bluetooth, chromebook, galaxy-s3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 phone and a Samsung ARM Chromebook. I have pictures on my phone that I would like to be able to transfer to my Chromebook without use of the cloud. Is there a tool or app I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be a [Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp&hl=en) app.

As alternative, you could try an [Android FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&hl=en) app which would work via a network connection.

Once you have an `SFTP` Server running on your phone, you can use the `FTP` protocol to download your pictures.

The format of the URL to be entered in your Chromebook browser:

```
ftp://username:password@example.com/test/
```

Make sure that you don't run this `FTP` server too long or too ofter as `FTP` tends to be a popular security hole. More secure would be `SFTP`.

Answer (score 2):

[AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). Transfer files over **Wifi** instead of **bluetooth**, much, much faster.

If you don't have a wireless network available, then turn your SGS3 into a [hotspot](http://www.fusiondub.com/how-to-turn-your-samsung-galaxy-s3-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot-2/) (may want to [disable data](http://inside-galaxy.blogspot.com/2013/06/samsung-galaxy-s3-how-to-turn-on-or-off_7.html)) and have your Chromebook connect to the phone's Access Point (AP).

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2014, it is possible to [use a USB cable to transfer file from an (sufficiently up-to-date) Android device to Chrome OS](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2692485/swap-files-between-your-android-device-and-chromebook-with-latest-update.html) using the MTP protocol.

[Update 38.0.2125.101](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/stable-channel-update-for-chrome-os.html) enables MTP for Chrome OS devices (except Chromeboxes). Connecting an MTP device (e.g., an up-to-date Android device) to an up-to-date Chrome OS device via a USB cable should cause the Files app to recognize the MTP device and enable copying files from it.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score -1):

Give [drop-box](http://dropbox.com) or [Google drive](http://www.google.com/drive%E2%80%8E) a try. You can upload the photos to either service from your galaxy and access from your Chromebook via drop-box/drive webpage.

Comment: The user said that he did not want to use the cloud, yet you suggest to use services that is cloud based.